# How to solve System.Net.FtpWebRequesT exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ftp, c#-3.0

My code works fine but sometimes i get `The type initializer for 'System.Net.FtpWebRequest' threw an exception.` error. I am downloading a csv from the FTP server and this is a part of my code.

```
  public static void Download(string FilePath)
        {
            FtpWebResponse response=null;
            try
            {

                FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                //Setting FTP attributes
                ftpserver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPDomain"].ToString() + "//" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPFileName"].ToString();
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpserver));
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPPass"]);

                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Proxy = null;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = false;

                 response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                //Delete File if Exist

                //Copying file 
                FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create);
                int Length = 2048;
                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
                int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                }
                writeStream.Close();
                response.Close();


               // HomeController.SalesStatus = "ok";
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {


            }
```

Normally i get the error on this line  `reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpserver));` Then i need to close my visual studio and restart the solution then it works fine. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Please post the exception detail. Inner Exception details, Stacktrace, whatever you got.

Comment: actually this is the only exception i had and then i restarted my solution and since then everything is back to normal. I am trying to find that error again but nothing working at the moment